# How to write a script that repeats the original link?

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I have a link called

```
www.example.com/previewAndAccept.php
```

but when I click the link, sometimes it redirects to:

```
www.example.com/NoMoreHits.php
```

Since it redirects I can't use the google chrome auto refresh script to refresh the URL, since it would be refreshing the second link instead of the first. My question is, is there a way to write a script to repeatedly check the original link every second?

Answer (score 1):

Well, supposedly TamperMonkey has access to the `window.location` object, so you could set `window.location.href` directly to the desired URL instead of just using `window.location.reload()`.

In your example something like this could work:

```
setInterval(
    () => window.location.href = 'http://www.example.com/previewAndAccept.php',
    delayInMilliseconds
)
```

ps.: Simply `window.location = 'http://www.example.com/previewAndAccept.php'` should work as well. Make sure to specify the protocol (`http` or `https`), otherwise the browser might just append the text to the end of the current path instead of replacing it.

Comment: But if the @match  is www.example.com/previewAndAccept.php, it'll just stop once it gets to www.example.com/NoMoreHits.php and stop refreshing, won't it?

Comment: Well, does adding `www.example.com/NoMoreHits.php` as a match have undesirable side effects? If not, then that could be a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```js
window.setInterval(function(){
  var a = document.getElementById('linkId');
  if (a) {
    a.setAttribute('href', 'www.example.com/previewAndAccept.php');
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<a href="www.example.com/previewAndAccept.php" title="this link" id="linkId">
  Link
</a>
```